# designer workflow to delete an item if it is 90 days older than created

Tags: designer-workflow

HI I am trying to create a designer workflow if the item is older than 90 days it should be deleted. Am trying this logic I created a calculated column named "deleteitem"

1. deleteitem = [Created]+90
2. in workflow my logic is
3. if current Item "Created" is greater than or equal to "deleteitem"

but it is not working as expected. Can some one tell if I am missing anything here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If working with SharePoint workflows, you could:

1. Set workflow to run on item create
2. Have its first step as Pause for X Days (In this case 90)
3. When it wakes up, delete the item.

[image: Pause For Action]

Comment: first step as pause is not showing in the workflow how to set it up ?

Comment: @user2314241 The action is "Pause For", which version of SharePoint and SharePoint Designer are you using?

Comment: Am using SharePoint designer 2010

Comment: See the image in my answer for the action. This is part of SharePoint 2010 workflows.

Comment: can i use copy item from one library to other after this condition will it work?

Comment: Is this to Archive the deleted records? After the pause, you can do any actions that you could usually. The workflow is effectively to sleep, then awoken by the timer job after X days. If you need to perform any other actions on the item, do so before deleting it and after the pause.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31656/discussion-between-user2314241-and-user19432).

Comment: I would recommend using `Pause until` instead of `Pause for`

Comment: @JamesFlattery Out of curiosity why would you recommend this?

Comment: With `Pause until` it doesn't matter when the last time the workflow ran... [Example](http://i.imgur.com/FWMNBZf.png)

Answer (score 9):

There is alternative approach you can take that doesn't involve a workflow, use [Information management policy](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-and-apply-information-management-policies-EB501FE9-2EF6-4150-945A-65A6451EE9E9).

1. Go into your list/library settings
2. Click Information management policy settings
3. Click Document or Item
4. Tick the Enable Retention box
5. Create a new retention stage that is Created plus 90 days and tell it to move the item to the recycle bin
6. Click OK 2 times and you are set, this will automatically delete the items (roughly) 90 days after they are created ([based on timer job settings](http://sharepointduffbert.com/2014/07/17/using-the-information-management-policy-specifically-the-retention-policy-in-sharepoint-2010/)).

Comment: Hi Alexander what if i have items existing already which are older than 90 days will this apply for them as well. That is the reason I am looking for workflow. Thanks

Comment: They should expire/be removed once the timer jobs on the server are run.